# div.appendChild(div) equivalent in ExtJS4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am transitioning my code to ExtJs4.1.1.
In one part of the code I have used Javascript's `appendChild()` method to add new `div` elements to an existing `div` container.

I want this to be done in ExtJs now.

**Existing code:**

```
var container = document.getElementById('treeContainer');
var nodeDiv = document.createElement("div");

// nodeDiv related code... setting properties and attributes
nodeDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='NodeContent'>" + node.displayText + "</div>";
nodeDiv.className = "Node";
//... more such code...

//add div to the container
container.appendChild(nodeDiv);
```

This code works perfectly fine.
But now I am using an ExtJs Panel wherein I want to display the same content.
How do I do it?

I tried doing:

```
xtype: 'panel',
autoScroll: true,
border: 10,
bodyStyle:{"background-color":"white"}, 
height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height *0.80,
id: 'treeContainer'

Ext.getCmp('treeContainer').update(nodeDiv); //this didnt work
Ext.getCmp('treeContainer').addChildEls(nodeDiv); //no success
```

I get this output on firing the below command in debugger:

```
Ext.getElementById('treeContainer') 

<div class=​"x-panel x-panel-default" style=​"height:​553.6px;​" id=​"treeContainer">​
[object HTMLDivElement]
​</div>​
```

Any help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel's [update](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-update) function expects a HTML string instead of a DOM object:

```
// using a HTML string
Ext.getCmp('treeContainer').update("<div class='NodeContent'>" + node.displayText + "</div>");

// using a DOM object
Ext.getCmp('treeContainer').update(nodeDiv.outerHTML);
```

Note, that using this function will always replace all existing HTML content in the panel.

---

If you really want to **append** HTML (i.e. preserve existing HTML content), you need to get a target element to append your HTML/DOM node to.

This could be the panel's default render target element:

```
var panel = Ext.getCmp('treeContainer'),
    renderEl = panel.isContainer ? panel.layout.getRenderTarget() : panel.getTargetEl();

// using a DOM node
renderEl.appendChild(nodeDiv);

// using a HTML string
renderEl.insertHtml('beforeEnd', "<div class='NodeContent'>" + node.displayText + "</div>");
```

Or - as this may change depending on your panel's layout - you just create a containg element in your initial [html](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-html) config:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    id: 'treeContainer',
    html: '<div class="html-content"></div>'
}
```

and append your content there:

```
Ext.getCmp('treeContainer').getEl().down('.html-content').appendChild(nodeDiv);
```

In any of the latter two cases, you should update the panel's layout afterwards, as you changed it's content manually:

```
Ext.getCmp('treeContainer').updateLayout();
```

Comment: Hi Matt, one issue. Quite understandably, after the updateLayout() is called the panel refreshes and loses the position where I was prior to this action. I want that the panel should freeze and keep updating at the same time so that user should not feel that it is refreshing everytime. Can I do this?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Using `suspendLayout: true` and it seems to be working the way I want it to.